# Valid SSL cert for laptop not connected to the internet

Tags: ssl

We have a laptop which isn't connected to the internet via wifi or mobile data, it has a wifi hotspot which is used to serve a website to an android phone. We want to demonstrate a webpage which uses the appcache technology on the phone

The problem is in chrome you require a valid certificate for a appcache, but how do you get a certificate for a laptop which isn't connected to anything?

Comment: export your certificate form Apache and manually import into chrome...

Answer (score 0):

In case the laptop is running linux.
You could try to create your own self-signed certificate using `openssl`.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Comment: "valid certificate", also we can make our own CA but then you get a warning on the phone that it might have been hacked so that's not ideal

Comment: You could create a .crt file of your self-signed certificate with `openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DM -in cert.pem -out cert.crt` and install it manually on the phone.

Comment: Going by my old notes we previously tried copying a pfx file to the phone via Settings-> Wifi -> Advanced -> Security Certificates install. This produced the security error